# What is a ISR G1 Router?

Tags: cisco

What does ISR stand for and what is an ISR G1 Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integrated Services Router](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10906/Products_Sub_Category_Home.html). The G1 was (I believe) the first model released in the ISR product line.

Comment: G1 stands for Generation 1, 1800, 2800, 3800 series are G1. Generation 2 was released with the 1900, 2900, and 3900 series routers.  Strangely enough there used to be a Catalyst 1900 series switch as well as a Mobile Wireless Edge Router 1900 series so the ISR naming is important when looking up at least the 1900 series routers.